# stream of list groupinngBy to map

Tags: java, treemap, groupingby

the example code I've been given is

```
public Map<String, List<Bier>> opzettenOverzichtBierenPerSoort() {
   //TODO
    
    return bieren.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bier::getSoort, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
}
```

input is a list of beer objects and it return a map of the kind of beer with all the beers in it.

now my question. wat are the second and third arguments in the groupingBy? I get the first one which states what it's grouped by...but the second and third seem a bit random.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on oracle's site? They have javadocs that explain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument is a `Supplier<M>`, which is used to produce a `Map` instance.

The third argument is a downstream `Collector`, which specifies what to do with the `Bier` elements which belong to a single group.

If you run the single argument variant:

```
return bieren.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bier::getSoort));
```

It will still collect the elements of each group into a `List` (that's the default behavior), but you don't have control over the type of `Map` that will map the `String` keys into the corresponding `List`s.

In your 3 argument example, you request that the `Map` will be a `TreeMap`, which means the keys will be sorted.

The current implementation of the single argument variant:

```
return bieren.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bier::getSoort));
```

is equivalent to:

```
return bieren.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bier::getSoort, HashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

which means the keys of the `Map` will not be sorted.